# Atomic rails4 windows 64bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devkit

Has anyone got a solution for this?  Ive tried everything online installing DevKit, env vars in paths etc and still nothing ....

```
C:\Sites>gem install rails
Fetching: atomic-1.1.14.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/RailsInstallerR/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
generating atomic_reference-i386-mingw32.def
make: *** [atomic_reference-i386-mingw32.def] Error 253


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstallerR/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstallerR/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: is there a `mkmf.log` in `C:/RailsInstallerR/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.14`? Or does it say anything on `C:/RailsInstallerR/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out`?

Answer (score 0):

on  window 7 64  bit system
1) if you want to work with ruby version less then ruby 2.0
2) you need to install DevKit  32 bit from  http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/  on window 7 x64 bit

if you want to install ruby 2 or greater version on window 7 64 bit so you need to install  DevKit  64 bit

with  ruby 2 with 64 bit

with DevKit 64 bit on window 7  64 bit system ruby 32 bit will not work

but window 7 64 bit system with Devkit 32 bit and ruby 32 bit will work

this issue will not come

Answer (score 0):

I too had almost the same problem while installing the latest version of rails with ruby193 installed on a Win7 machine. The installation used to break while running extconf.rb and with a error in creating Makefile as well.

I too had installed DevKits for ruby193 and set all environments, used pik to set the correct ruby version etc etc. But still it failed to install the latest rails.

So I tried installing older version of rails (3.0.5) and it installed perfectly. If you can do your work with an older version then you can try installing 3.0.5 using the following command :

```
gem install rails --version 3.0.5
```

Hope that works!